# Apparent random slowniness on apache 2.4 on HTTPS and HTTP

Tags: linux, networking, apache-2.4, tcp

Hello currently I experience random slowniness in apache 2.4.18 on HTTPS on Ubuntu server 16.04. Here follow observations, symptoms and info:

- it doesn't happen with HTTP
- it doesn't happen with about 2k used slots in apache's `/server-status`. It happens from 2.7k upwards (I've seen the status reach even 4.2k used slots)
- `time curl -vI <url>` is stuck in `Trying <ip address>` and responds in 1 to 30 seconds (the average processing time, when not slow, is 0.2s). While stuck, `tcpdump -n | grep '<ip address of request>'` shows no incoming packets in the server: they appear once curl goes on
- apache is using mpm_prefork with the following settings

```
StartServers                     10
MinSpareServers           50
MaxSpareServers          100
ServerLimit     20000
MaxRequestWorkers         20000
MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
```

- apache's `/server-status` page shows many (hundreds) free slots
- server resources average usage: cpu 30%, load average 20, ram used 35%, disk io r/w very low
- some tuning attempts on the TCP queues (https://blog.cloudflare.com/syn-packet-handling-in-the-wild/)

  - `ss -n state syn-recv sport = :443 | wc -l` shows a maximum number of 130 when launched repeatedly. It seems that `curl` hangs when this number is close to 130
  - `net.core.somaxconn` was 128, I did set it to 4096 with `sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=4096`, then even reloaded apache
  - I've launched `sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog=4096`
  - `ss -plnt sport = :443` shows something like

```
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port
LISTEN     0      128         :::443                     :::*                   users:(("apache2",pid=184902,fd=8),<4000 more apache processes>
```

Honestly I don't know if the queues tuning has been effective.

I'd like to first find out how to troubleshoot the problem to find out the part responsible of the slowniness, so any hint on troubleshooting is appreciated. Thank you

**Edit 1**

OK there's 1 thing that maybe I didn't try (for avoiding a downtime in production): the restart of apache. I thought that the TCP queue of the port 443 was handled by the system *alone*, i.e. without asking apache which was its limit: **wrong**. After the restart the queue was finally free to go over 130: in fact, in the first seconds after the apache restart the queue hit the apache limit of 511.

Now that the queue seems ok curl isn't stuck anymore on `Trying to connect`; now the problem seems on the apache side, which seems slow even on HTTP.

More information:

- the request url I'm using is being handled by an apache VirtualHost, which just issues a `Redirect`
- here follows the information on the SSL cache

```
SSL/TLS Session Cache Status:
cache type: SHMCB, shared memory: 512000 bytes, current entries: 2176
subcaches: 32, indexes per subcache: 88
time left on oldest entries' objects: avg: 229 seconds, (range: 209...247)
index usage: 77%, cache usage: 99%
total entries stored since starting: 43916
total entries replaced since starting: 0
total entries expired since starting: 0
total (pre-expiry) entries scrolled out of the cache: 41740
total retrieves since starting: 586 hit, 83648 miss
total removes since starting: 0 hit, 0 miss
```

So please share any thoughts on how to troubleshoot the slowniness. Thank you

Comment: Do you have swap enabled and if so, is apache using it?  That could cause some of the performance problems you're experiencing.

This is an article I've used for a somewhat similar apache problem i had: https://community.mellanox.com/s/article/linux-sysctl-tuning

Comment: why do you use prefork instead of event? check the apache user is not reaching system limit of processes of something of the likes. Also if your peaks are about 2000,3000 users do not assign a max of 20.000. Some overall finetuning is designed for the amount of load you are talking about.

Comment: forgot to mention that for a 2000 peak loads minspare/maxspare is incredibly low

Comment: @Logan I've tried those that I did understand. Later I discovered what kept limiting me (I will put it in edit 1, spoiler: I've been dumb)

Comment: @ezra-s If i recall correctly for using event and PHP I needed to use a proxy: the amount of traffic didn't justify out-of-comfort zone of configuring a proxy instead of the classical installation of php and apache. How much would you suggest for minspare and maxspare and why?

Comment: @reallynice Misconfort is what you are experiencing right now for not using the correct mpm. Prefork may be good and fast if lots of processes are opened beforehand for big loads, but to CPU it is too costly to open new processes, so with an average of 2000 clients, I would at least try to have as many Spare as peak variations, so depending on the load spikes I would for 200-500 spares, so when new clients request they do not have to wait for the system to open a new process. That's why event is recommended.

Comment: It is also much clear to debug an issue when php is running in its correct place (php-ffpm) and httpd does what it does best, with its own native libraries (instead of the burden of third party libraries to interpret programming).

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=mpm_event+php-fpm

Comment: maybe your troubles are related to the OCSP stapling or DNS resolving of your apache httpd?